# Identify that an Any is actually a scala enumeration value

Tags: scala, enums

I have a string formatting function `fmt(v:Any): String` that needs to do different things depending on the runtime type of `v`. So it looks something like:

```
def fmt(v:Any): String = {
  v match {
    case a: Int => "Int: " + a
    case a: String => "\"" + a + "\""
    case a => throw new IllegalArgumentException(s"??? '$a', ${a.getClass.getCanonicalName}?!")
  }
}
```

This throws an `IllegalArgumentException("??? 'myVal', scala.Enumeration.Val?!")` when I pass in a scala enumeration value. However, adding a

```
case a: scala.Enumeration.Val => "Hello enum"
```

doesn't compile: *object Enumeration is not a member of package scala
Note: class Enumeration exists, but it has no companion object.*

How can I detect that the instance passed in is a scala enumeration value?

`if (a.getClass.getCanonicalName == "scala.Enumeration.Val")` should work, but feels like quite a hack - is there any actually typed pattern matching I can do instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've made two mistakes.  First, the name of the class for the public API of an Enumeration is `Value` not `Val`.  Secondly, when referring to inner classes, you use `#` rather than `.`.  The latter denotes an inner class of a specific instance; the former means "for some `Enumeration`, I don't care which, this is an instance of its inner class Value").

So, write it like this:

```
case a: scala.Enumeration#Value => "Hello, enum!"
```

If you actually mean you need to know when it's the protected implementation class `Val` instead of the public-facing `Value`, you can't easily because, well, it's protected.  It's supposed to be an implementation detail.  But you can put your match inside something that extends Enumeration, and then you can get at `Val`.  (Using `#` notation.)